# When file/folder is renamed, how to view the old name details in commit log/commit history?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, file-rename

In SourceTree, when a file is renamed then in commits it is displayed with the icon [image] and the new name. But how do I find the old name in SourceTree?

Here I changed the name of the `app` folder to `app-new-name`:

[image]

I could not find the old name anymore.

Comment: Just type `git status` on console and you'll set it.

Comment: Can git status command be used to see the old commit details by passing the commit ID? I need it for old commits as well and not for uncommitted changes alone

Comment: Well, I only use git cli but you can do everything on cli that you can to with sourcetree.
`git status` shows the current changes. For old commit, you should check for file history.
If you want to see a commit history of file; `git log -- [filename]`,
also you can see more info with; `git log --stat -C -- [filename]`

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the file and choose 'Log Selected...'. In the dialog that appears, tick the checkbox 'Follow renamed files' in the right bottom; then you can browse to older commits and look up the old filename at the top of the dialog (but not the title, that's the current filename).

[image]